# How to call main activity method in Recyclerview adapter class

Tags: java, android, class, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

Suppose i have a public method names TestMe() and i wanna use this method in Recycler view adapter class so how to possible it.

I m using as 
declare first 
MainActivity activity=new MainActivity();
activity.TestMe();

but it showing an error null exception

Comment: you can use method by using interface .

Comment: `((MainActivity)context).TestMe();` pass activity context to adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass your Activity's reference to Adapter in Constructor or set it by setter method and call your TestMe method.

```
if(activity instanceof MainActivity){
    ((MainActivity)activity).TestMe();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not a good idea to store an Activity  reference, so use interface instead.

Create interface

```
interface MyInterface{
    public void textMe();
}
```

Make Activity implement interface

```
class MainActivity implements MyInterface {
…
```

pass MyInterface instance to adapter in constructor like this

```
public MyAdapter(MyInterface interface){
    this.interface = interface;
}
```

and then use like this

```
this.interface.textMe();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not create instance your activity by `MainActivity activity=new MainActivity();`.

Correct method is using *instanceof*

```
if(context instanceof MainActivity){

  MainActivity activity = (MainActivity)context;
  activity.TestMe(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your activity where you create and set adapter, pass your activity object in constructor:

```
setAdapter(new Adapter(this));
```

Store this in your adapter.

```
Adapter(Activity act){
   this.act = act;
}
```

Then, call this method using activity object.

```
act.TestMe();
```

Comment: If you are using support library, use AppCompatActivity instead of Activity.